# Where did a '95-'96 Sycamore mtb fit in the Mongoose product range?

Tags: mountain-bike, commuting-bike, steel, history

From what I've managed to piece together trawling the internets, this period was before quality dropped for Mongoose, but that Sycamores were low- to mid-range models. I'm considering how much time and effort to spend on overhauling a bike like this for commuting btw, I'm from outside the States, if that matters.

Comment: Regarding the 'outside the states' bit - where I live Mongoose is sold in bike shops, not in big-box *marts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Sycamore could only be considered a mid-range bike. It had reasonable entry level components but nothing great.

The tange chromoly frame would make a good base for a commuter but I think this was only a part frame so it may be quite heavy as opposed to a full chromoly frame. You would struggle to find a replacement fork if you were changing that due to its 1 inch head set. Not sure on the bottom bracket if it was cartridge this would be an easy change. It doesn't have tabs for disc brakes.U